# React.js invalid hook call error tow react and react-dom modules

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, react-dom, rerender

I am working on project I tried every possible way to make my Component rerender based on props everytime I got invalid hook call error. Same thing does conditional rendering I tried countless of variations. But then I started checking whether there are other possible causes besides my rule breaking code.

And I found this...
`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "zustand": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "typescript-language-server": "^0.11.2",
    "vite": "^3.0.4"
  }
```

`

Could this be the issue?

Comment: What you shared is just list of dependencies, it have nothing to do with your code. Please provide [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.